# How can I direct an href inside the same page in a frame/box

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
  a{
    text-decoration: none;
  }
</style>
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
  <button id = "find-me">Show my location</button><br/>
    <p id = "status"></p>
    <a id = "map-link" target="_self"></a>
  <script>
    function geoFindMe() {

      const status = document.querySelector('#status');
      const mapLink = document.querySelector('#map-link');

      mapLink.href = '';
      mapLink.textContent = '';

      function success(position) {
        const latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
        const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      
        status.textContent = '';
        mapLink.href = `https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/${latitude}/${longitude}`;
        mapLink.textContent = `Latitude: ${latitude} °, Longitude: ${longitude} °`;
      }

      function error() {
        status.textContent = 'Unable to retrieve your location';
      }

      if(!navigator.geolocation) {
        status.textContent = 'Geolocation is not supported by your browser';
      } else {
        status.textContent = 'Locating…';
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
      }

      }

      document.querySelector('#find-me').addEventListener('click', geoFindMe);
      
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically what i want is something like this:
https://www.maps.ie/coordinates.html,
to take this href from code and to open it on the same page under the say of the latitude and longitude that I get.
but I don't know how to do it, I tried using target self, and it doesn't do what I want to.

i tried the suggestion of using iframe, but the src doesnt work with this it says that the url refuses to connect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.ASP). Just replace `<a id = "map-link" target="_self"></a>` with iframe and set `src` instead.

Comment: I tried using iframe, but it doesnt work for me.
because i put on the src "https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/${latitude}/${longitude}"
and also tried without /${latitude}/${longitude}